# How to add button listener to ListView?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom list item `XML` with 2 `Buttons` and I want to get when one is clicked (and a way of knowing which one). My `ListView` is made with data from a database. This is what I use for populating the list:

```
private DBManager manager;
private Cursor cursor;
private ListView lista;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.m_home_layout);

    manager = new DBManager(this);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);



    String[] from = new String[]{manager.CN_NAME, manager.CN_DESCRIPTION, manager.CN_TIME, manager.CN_DAY};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.list_title, R.id.list_description, R.id.list_time, R.id.list_day};
    cursor = manager.cargarCursorData("data");
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to,0);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

I've seen people saying that you have to use `bindView` but I don't have anything like that and I don't know what it is. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: you should move on to recyclerview, it's much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through this tutorials for Creating Custom `Adapter`, in which you can get the which `Button` is clicked:

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html

http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Comment: I'll check them out, second one seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you.